# SSRS 2005 - Mix graphical (charts) and textual representation of information

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I need to build a report using sql server reporting services 2005, where one column should be displayed as one solid bar chart and other as simple text datafields. 
Like this: 
[image: Graph image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSH2i.png

Is there a way to add datafieled to a bar chart or make a chart that would not be separated row by row dataset?